# What is the significance of #if 1 in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I found some programs with `#if` type of statements. What is the significance of this `#if 1`? Here is the code fragment:

```
   for (;;) {
        register const uint8_t* m_pos;
        unsigned m_off;
        unsigned m_len;
        unsigned dindex;

        D_INDEX1(dindex,ip);
        GINDEX(m_pos,m_off,dict,dindex,in);
        if (LZO_CHECK_MPOS_NON_DET(m_pos,m_off,in,ip,M4_MAX_OFFSET))
        goto literal;
#if 1
    if (m_off <= M2_MAX_OFFSET || m_pos[3] == ip[3])
    goto try_match;
    D_INDEX2(dindex,ip);
#endif
    GINDEX(m_pos,m_off,dict,dindex,in);
    if (LZO_CHECK_MPOS_NON_DET(m_pos,m_off,in,ip,M4_MAX_OFFSET))
        goto literal;
    if (m_off <= M2_MAX_OFFSET || m_pos[3] == ip[3])
        goto try_match;
    goto literal;

 try_match:
```

Comment: Basically it's instead of a comment. You can change it to 0 and quickly 'cancel' the statements between the #if and the #endif from being processed. It's for the programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a relic of someone playing with the code. It does absolutely nothing, but change the 1 to a 0, and the area between the `#if` and the `#endif` gets excluded from compilation.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` is a "do nothing", but it can be useful if the code contained within is something you want to disable quickly.

It's somewhat better than a big block comment since it allows block comments internally.